# How to transfer folders with many mp3 files in it from pc to itunes?

Tags: itunes

I want to transfer some folders that concludes many mp3 files in them.
Is it possible totransfer folders not a file?

Answer (score 1):

Drag a file or folder from the desktop to the iTunes window. If you add a folder, all the files it contains are added to your library.